# Reuse an Injectable Service in typescript console app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an injectable service that is used by a component.

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
    constructor(private http: Http){}
    ...
}
```

At the same time, I am trying to write a utility app(console app to view data) in typescript.

```
class SomeConsoleApp{
    constructor(svc:SomeService){}
    ...
    run(){
      console.log('test');
   }
}

var svc = new SomeService(???);
var app = new SomeConsoleApp(svc);
app.run();
```

My question is, how can I initialize the Http parameter when I initialize the `SomeService`. The angular2 Http takes in two parameters - ConnectionBackend and RequestOptions. Kind of like a poor-man's dependency injection.

Comment: You can try `injector.get("SomeService")`.

Comment: What module is injector?

Comment: Each component has its own injector. You're looking for an injector where your service has been registered, so I'll guess it is root node - app module.

Comment: yes, it is in the app.module.ts. So what is the syntax to initialize the service?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your root injector outside the Angular application, you'll need to keep a reference on it when bootstrapping the module.

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then((moduleRef: NgModuleRef<any>) => {
  someGlobalObject = moduleRef.injector;
});
```

Then you can use the injector to create new service with all its dependencies:

```
var svc = someGlobalObject.inject("SomeService");
```

Note: This can only work if your console application and Angular application are running inside the same execution context (same page).

Comment: I will be using ts-node to run the TS file.

Comment: Well, you need to bootstrap the Angular app somewhere, try before your class declaration. May I suggest using actual unit tests instead of console to test behaviour?

Comment: I thought about the test approach too. For my usage, it's more of a utility. The TS file resides in the same project as the angular app.